# Can a Warlock with the Witch Sight invocation see both the true form and the illusionary or transmuted form?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, illusion

The Witch Sight warlock invocation reads:

> You can see the true form of any shapechanger or creature concealed by illusion or transmutation magic while the creature is within 30 feet of you and within line of sight.

If you are looking at, say, a creature under the effect of *true polymorph*, are you aware of how the creature appears to others? In other words, if a humanoid polymorphs into a bear, you perceive the humanoid but do you know it is currently in bear form, or do you need to ask a nearby bystander?

Comment: Very helpful, exactly what I was trying to get at while attempting brevity. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes.**

The intention is more or less to mimic a *limited* version of *True Seeing*, which provides Truesight, and it is worded similarly:

Truesight: PHB, page 185.

> A creature with truesight **can**, out to a specific range, see...

Witch Sight, as you indicated, PHB, page 111

> You **can** see the true form of...

**If the spell or ability indicated you could "*only* see the true form of," it would have been worded that way.**

Again, Truesight, PHB, page 185:

> Furthermore, the creature **can** see into the Ethereal Plane.

Clearly, this does not indicate the creature can *only* see into the Ethereal Plane, as he would be then blind on the material.  This further affirms the previous usage of the word "can."